# Exact 2 centres of symmetry

Tags: geometry

I have to answer and prove the answer to the following question:

> There exists figures in plane with exactly 2 centres of symmetry?

I know to show that closed figures have at most 1 centre of symmetry.
But I don't know to show that unclosed (opened) figures have at most 1 centre of symmetry, to complete the demonstration.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: It is not true that an arbitrary point set can have at most 1 center of symmetry (for instance, take the entire plane).  So it depends somewhat on what exactly a “figure” is defined to be.  Are there any restrictions?  For general figures it is very far from true that non-closed sets are open.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997741/centre-of-symmetry-of-a-bound-figure?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f,g\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ be non-identity symmetry maps of some figure $X$ with unique fixpoints $F_f$ and $F_g$, respectively. Then $h:=f\circ g\circ f^{-1}$ is a symmetry map of $X$ invariant and has unique fixpoint $F_h:=f(F_g)$. Now if $F_f\ne F_g$, then $F_h=F(f_g)\ne f(F_f)=F_f$ as well as $F_h=f(F_g)\ne F_g$ (because $f$ does not leave $F_g$ invariant), i.e., there are at least three centres of symmetry.

Upon closer inspection, one finds that the set of symmetry centres is infinite an unbounded in the situation above.