# What is the terminology for the center of a symmetric object?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, terminology, analytic-geometry

Consider this object

[image]

It is very complicated but nonetheless we can immediately see that it has a center point.

or this object, which has a center and both objects share a common one.

[image]

Is there a generic terminology for such points?

Comment: Ummm... "center of mass"?

Comment: Center of symmetry? Any bounded 3D shape with at least two distinct axes of rotational symmetry has a unique such point - the intersection of these two (and in fact, of all) axes

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997741/centre-of-symmetry-of-a-bound-figure?rq=1).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I prefer "centroid" for geometry since the object could have an uneven mass density distribution.